# Jquery Autocomplete scroll bar not appearing in IE 

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, autocomplete, scrollbar

I am using latest version of jQuery Autocompletion plugin and have populated an array (as input for autocomplete) of about 800 entries. Now strangely when I type a letter which triggers large results (causing a scroll bar), I can see a scrollbar in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

I have only included the files `jquery.autocomplete.css` and `jquery.autocomplete.js` in my JSP. Should I need to include anything else?

**Edit:** my CSS is as follows:

```
.ac_results {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.ac_results ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.ac_results li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    /* 
    if width will be 100% horizontal scrollbar will apear 
    when scroll mode will be used
    */
    /*width: 100%;*/
    font: menu;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* 
    it is very important, if line-height not setted or setted 
    in relative units scroll will be broken in firefox
    */
    line-height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE does it break in? Do you have other conflicting CSS on your page? This seems to work fine in IE8: http://jsbin.com/ajudu

Comment: thank you, i am also using IE8 and do not have any coflicting css. i have included only those two specified files do not know what might have went wrong!

Comment: working in mozilla, also not working in eclipse internal browser

Comment: If you could give us a link to a page that has the problem (or recreate it on http://jsbin.com) we might be able to help. Since I can't duplicate the issue, the only other advise I can give you is to use the IE Developer Toolbar to find out what's going on with the CSS. You might also want to try and uncomment that `width: 100%;` line in jquery.autocomplete.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this additional check for document.body.style.maxHeight in the jquery.autocomplete.js fixed the issue for me:

```
                if($.browser.msie && 
                    ((typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined") ||
                    (document.body.style.maxHeight == '')))
```

It is around line 735

Comment: By the way, the issue does not appear if you set a proper doctype (so that IE does not enter quirks mode):
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

Changing dtd solved the problem for me:

See this for more info:
http://old.nabble.com/-autocomplete--Problem-with-Scrolling-IE-7-td20758062s27240.html

/Olle